# In Java why Thread class is created as Concrete Class?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

We know that there are two ways to create a Thread in Java.

1. Implementing Runnable Interface
2. Extending the Thread Class [Thread is a Concrete Class with default implementation for run() method]

In the second approach, we have to provide the implementation for run() method to have our thread logic, executed. If so, then why JDK developers have not made run() method as abstract in Thread Class?

I am interested in knowing the reason behind, providing the default implementation for run() method in Thread Class.

Comment: You're forgetting about the `t1 = Thread(runnable)` syntax

Comment: Tip of the day: forget Thread implements Runnable and always use the constructor new Thread(new MyRunnable());

Comment: Thanks a lot aruisdante that answers my question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `Thread#run()` was abstract, then following would be a compile error:

```
Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable);
```

Comment: If Thread#run() was abstract, [then] the following, _which is a_ better _way to create a new thread,_ would be a compile error

Answer (score 3):

You have almost answered your own question.  Here is the default implementation of run

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

That is, the default implementation invokes the Runnable that was passed in via the constructor.   Which is the first approach that you mentioned in your question.

```
new Thread( runnable ).start();
```

If run had instead been declared as abstract, then as kajacx has also pointed out; then that approach would not have compiled.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot have abstract methods in non abstract class!**

So having a abstract method in `Thread` would have to make `Thread` class abstract as well. Then why stop there? Make it an interface. But wait.. we already have `Runnable` interface that Thread class implements.

Also note we call `start()` method and not the `run()` method. start() will start a new Thread of execution. run() will just run the method in current Thread.

Also run() method is overridden. The method comes from Runnable interface.

```
public
interface Runnable {
    public abstract void run();
}
```

Extending Thread is just an alternate way for Thread creation and it cannot be abstract as you will not be able to create Thread Objects without writing a concrete implementation yourself.

Comment: The OP is aware of this, their question is why is ``Thread`` not an abstract class.